# Multiple zookeeper server start issue

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

I am able to run single zookeeper instance on my windows machine. but getting success to setup multiple zookeeper instances on single windows machine.

As per guideline I did following steps:

1. Creating multiple zoo.conf file into conf folder. Structure as below

   zookeeper_home---|
                       conf--|
                             zoo.cfg
                             zoo_2.cfg
                             zoo_3.cfg
2. zoo.cfg

> ```
> tickTime=2000
> initLimit=10
> syncLimit=5
> dataDir=c:/opt/zookeeper/data
> clientPort=2181
> server.1=localhost:2888:3888
> server.2=localhost:2889:3889
> server.3=localhost:2890:3890
> ```

3. zoo_2.cfg

> ```
>  tickTime=2000
>  initLimit=10
>  syncLimit=5
>  dataDir=c:/opt/zookeeper/data2
>  clientPort=2182
>  server.1=localhost:2888:3888
>  server.2=localhost:2889:3889
>  server.3=localhost:2890:3890
> ```

4. zoo_3.cfg

> ```
> tickTime=2000
> initLimit=10
> syncLimit=5
> dataDir=c:/opt/zookeeper/data3
> clientPort=2183
> server.1=localhost:2888:3888
> server.2=localhost:2889:3889
> server.3=localhost:2890:3890
> ```

5. As each file has dataDir, I have created folder as

> c:/opt/zookeeper/data
>
> c:/opt/zookeeper/data2
>
> c:/opt/zookeeper/data3

Also created myid file in each of above folder with number 1,2,3 respectively.
now whenever I am trying to start server as `c:\opt\zookeeper\bin>zkServer.cmd` 
it is throwing an error as

> Cannot open channel to 2 at election address localhost/127.0.0.1:3889
>
> Cannot open channel to 3 at election address localhost/127.0.0.1:3890
>
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

looks like server not started, but how I can start these server parallely? or is I have to user any other approach.

Comment: Have you started all three of the servers? These exceptions are a normal part of ZooKeeper's interaction with the ensemble. ZooKeeper is designed to be able to handle not communicating with other servers in a quorum. It's possible that once they're all started you will see these exceptions disappear.

Comment: That's true, but how to start all 3 servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default, zkEnv.cmd will use the zoo.cfg as the default configuration file. And if you execute your command `c:\opt\zookeeper\bin>zkServer.cmd`, then only one instance start up with configuration zoo.cfg

So if you want to start up three instances:

1. either you copy three zookeeper package, and each has its own zoo.cfg, and execute following command for each `c:\opt\zookeeper1\bin>zkServer.cmd`, `c:\opt\zookeeper2\bin>zkServer.cmd`, `c:\opt\zookeeper3\bin>zkServer.cmd`
2. Or you can modify zkEnv.cmd, and make it accept the parameter as the configuration file, the you can execute `zkServer.cmd ../conf/zoo.cfg`, `zkServer.cmd ../conf/zoo2.cfg`, `zkServer.cmd ../conf/zoo3.cfg`

For alternative #2, you also need to update log4j configuration, so you can have different log file for each instances, so simply, just copy 3 folders, and modify each zoo.cfg

Check the code:

zkEnv.cmd

> set ZOOCFG=%ZOOCFGDIR%\zoo.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you've not created myid file in dataDir of all zookeeper instances. 
Make this file for all zookeeper instances and write corresponding server id such as 1 for first instance,2 for second instance,3 for third instance.
Save all files and first restart your all three instances and then check their status.

Answer (score 0):

Google has the answer
[image]

You can just follow the [detail instruction](https://dzone.com/articles/running-multiple-zookeeper-instances-on-single-win), I cannot copy/paste the whole article, hence attached the image